# How to pass generic shebang line to shell

Tags: command-line, external-command

As far as I know, all "good" scripts/programs start off with a shebang line as the first line:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/env python
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

etc.  Is it possible to pass that line to Vim in `command`-mode to generically determine the program to use when executing the current file.

For example, perl file needs

```
:! perl%
```

Python,

```
:! python%
```

If the shebang is already there in the file, is it possible to replace the specific program **before** the **%** character (current file) with the shebang line/argument?

Of course, if the file is executable already `:! ./%` works

---

The idea is to map a key so that, as you write code, simply hitting a shortcut key the file is executed; mimicking an IDE.

**Once again, assuming the file is not (yet) executable, since you just started writing it in Vim.**

Comment: So far, [this Q/A](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7730/run-file-though-a-command-when-opening-from-explore) fits into this category well.

Comment: I suppose the easiest thing to do here is to give execute permissions to the file; e.g. from within vim itself: `:! chmod +x %`.  Then, the rest is taken care of with the available shebang line already in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want but you could try this mapping using the `<F7>` key:

```
nnoremap <F7> :<C-U>sil! exe '!' . matchstr(getline(1), '#!\zs.*') . ' ' . shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1) <Bar> redraw!<CR>
```

- `matchstr(getline(1), '#!\zs.*')` extract the text after the shebang
- `shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)` expand the full path to the current file and protect characters that may have a special meaning for the shell; the second non-nul argument is useful to escape special items such as `!`, `%`, `#` which could be expanded by Vim on the command-line

If you want to see the output in the shell, you could remove `:sil!` and `:redraw!`:

```
nnoremap <F7> :<C-U>exe '!' matchstr(getline(1), '^#!\zs.*') shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)<CR>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the fact that your shell understands the Shebang:

```
:!./%
```

Please be sure to make your file executable (`chmod +x filename`). You can easily create a mapping for this, so that you can execute your current file with one keypress.

Comment: Yea, I should've clarified that part of the question; if the file is executable, doing `:! %` works

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason @cbaumhardt's answer doesn't work for you, you can actually just use `perl`.  As a handy helper for systems that don't handle shebang lines correctly, perl will actually honor the shebang line itself.  See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563832/why-dont-i-get-any-syntax-errors-when-i-execute-my-python-script-with-perl) for more info about that.

Comment: That's an awesome tidbit of information! Unfortunately, it does not apply here.  The idea is to map a key so that, as you write code, simply hitting a shortcut key the file is executed.

Comment: Once again, assuming the file is not (*yet*) executable, since you just started writing it in Vim.

Comment: @ILMostro_7 so this clearly doesn't have the keybinding, but running `:! perl %` doesn't require the file to be executable, but it does honor the shebang line without having to parse it yourself, though user9433424's solution looks like just what you want

Comment: Perl is looking more and more interesting and powerful the older it gets.