# Run file though a command when opening from Explore

Tags: autocmd, filetype

I have configured vim to automatically decompile ".class" files similar to the instructions in: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip54.

I have made a minor change to use [cfr_0_115](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/) as below:

```
augr class
au!
au bufreadpost,filereadpost *.class silent %!java -jar /blah/cfr_0_115.jar %
au bufreadpost,filereadpost *.class set readonly
au bufreadpost,filereadpost *.class set ft=java
au bufreadpost,filereadpost *.class silent normal gg=G
au bufreadpost,filereadpost *.class set nomodified
augr END
```

This works fine when opening files from the shell.

Sometimes I work with JAR files and would like to achieve the following workflow:

1. `:Explore` (and navigate to the JAR file)
2. View the JAR file and select a Class
3. When this Class is opened, it should be ran through CFR.

Currently, when I get to step "3" the class is not decompiled for viewing. I'd love to know how I can get the class file from a JAR opened 'through' the class decompiler.

**Edit 1** - 
With Vim logging enabled, when I open a class file that is NOT within a JAR file, I see `Executing BufRead Auto commands for "*.class` include the command I wish to run. However, when I open the class file from within a jar, I do not see the command in the logs.

**Edit 2** - 
Relevant log entries when opening a JAR:

```
Executing BufReadCmd Auto commands for "zipfile:*/*"
autocommand call zip#Read(expand("<amatch>"), 1)

Calling shell to execute: "(unzip -p -- '/blah/original-httpclienttest-1.0.jar' 'com/atlassianlabs/sslclient/Main.class') >/var/folders/ys/18xytj217f749_vx7rhs4t7w0000gp/T/vwqRYKe/1 2>&1"
chdir(zipfile:/blah/original-httpclienttest-1.0.jar::com/)
fchdir() to previous dir
Reading viminfo file "/blah/.viminfo" marks
```

and later:

```
Executing BufRead Auto commands for "*.class"
autocommand setf stata
```

However when I open a class file by navigating to it directly with the file explore (:Explore) I see:

```
Executing BufRead Auto commands for "*.class"
autocommand silent %!java -jar /blah/cfr_0_115.jar
```

**Follow-up**

I don't know why the autocmd's that exist are not getting picked up when opening from a JAR, because VIM is actually running some autocmd, just not the one I want and "autocommand setf stata" is not even present when opening a class. I'm blocked in terms of how to debug this further.

**More Follow-up**

I got this working to some extent by adding a function to the filetype.vim file on class files. However, vim reports the file name in the format: ZIPFILEPATH::PATHTOCLASS in the JAR.. I was hoping it would send though the temp file path instead.

Comment: I don't know why the autocommand doesn't trigger when you open the file from a JAR but a workaround could be to put in your vimrc a function which will execute your list of commands, bind a key to call the function and use it to manually decompile the file.

Comment: How are you looking within the JAR? 7-zip or something? I'm not sure but I'm guessing that the fact that the file is compressed is messing with vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By starting vim using: `vim -V9aLogFile.log` I was able to determine that when `:Explore` opens a file, it checks the content of filetype.vim and autocmd's are working from there.

Because vim reports the filename of a class inside a jar file in the format `zipfile::path-to-jar::path-to-class` I needed to workaround that as my Java decompiler couldn't handle this type of file path.

I created a shell "wrapper" script:

```
#!/bin/sh

pathToDecompiler=/blah/cfr_0_115.jar


fileType=$(echo $* | cut -f1 -d:)
jarFile=$(echo $* | cut -f2 -d:) 
classFile=$(echo $* | cut -f4 -d:) 
uuid=$(uuidgen)


if [ $fileType = "zipfile" ]
then
    tmpDir=/tmp/$uuid
    unzip -qq $jarFile $classFile -d $tmpDir 
    java -jar $pathToDecompiler $tmpDir/$classFile
    rm -rf /tmp/$uuid/ >&/dev/null
else
    java -jar $pathToDecompiler $*
fi
```

The above script handles two cases, when opening a normal class file, and when opening a class file from the Explore Command, it creates a file in temp. Note: when writing this, I found entering `rm -rf ...` particularly scary in the event a variable didn't get populated. I decided to play it safe and hard-code '/tmp'.

Then I created a function back in the filetype.vim file:

```
" Java Class
au BufRead *.class call SetClassOptions()
function SetClassOptions()
     setf stata
     silent %!/blah/get-class-from-jar.sh %
     set readonly
     set ft=java
     silent normal gg=G
     set nomodified
endfunction
```

It's a little hacky, and I am sure it could be polished or completed in a more 'vim' way, but at least it has my usecase sorted.

final result is recorded: https://giphy.com/gifs/l41Yf8WlUQWj3R6hy